# Access a kivy screenmanager created in a kv file through the py file

Tags: python, kivy

i want to create the ScreenManager in the kv file, but i also need th change the shown screen in the .py file. Thats because i have to create some buttons
dynamically and bind a specific function to them, which will change to a specific (button related) screen. Creating the buttons is way more convient in python. So the main question is: how to access the screenmanager created in a kv file through the py file? 
To explain it a bit futher, here is some code:

kv file

```
#: kivy 1.10.1

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    FirstScreen:
        id: first_screen
        name: 'FirstScreen'
        manager: 'screen_manager'
    SecondScreen:
        id: second_screen
        name: 'SecondScreen'
        manager: 'screen_manager'
```

py file

```
from kivy.modules import console
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    MenuScreen = ObjectProperty(None)

    def SwitchToSecond(self):
        print(ScreenManagement.current)
        ScreenManagement.current = "TestScreen"


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class testApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testApp().run()
```

thank you for any guidance in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the [`ScreenManager`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager) within a Screen you must use its [`manager`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.Screen.manager) attribute, but for this you must not create a property with the same name, in your case you are doing it which is considered a bad practice.

Modifying your code and adding some elements we obtain the following example:

***.kv**

```
#: kivy 1.10.1

ScreenManager:
    id: screen_manager

    FirstScreen:
        id: first_screen
        name: 'FirstScreen'
        Button:
            text: "First"
            on_press: first_screen.SwitchToSecond()
    SecondScreen:
        id: second_screen
        name: 'SecondScreen'
        Label:
            text: "second"
```

**.*py**

```
from kivy.modules import console
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class FirstScreen(Screen):
    MenuScreen = ObjectProperty(None)

    def SwitchToSecond(self):
        self.manager.current = "SecondScreen"


class SecondScreen(Screen):
    pass


class testApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    testApp().run()
```

Comment: Thanky you for this clarification. The only thing i dont like in you version, is that you have write all the design into the screenmanager directly.

Comment: @eB_Bo 
It is an example because I thought you wanted to use it in SwitchToSecond, there are really many ways to get ScreenManager depending on where you want to get it, for example we can take advantage of the fact that the ScreenManager is the root and we use `sm = App.get_running_app().root`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example using the ScreenManager (I also added a method inside of the MyScreenManager class that accepts a `value`, which would correspond to the name of the screen you would like to change to, but not necessary for this app to run):

**Python**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

class Screen1(Screen):

    pass

class Screen2(Screen):

    pass

class Screen3(Screen):

    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):

    def changescreen(self, value):

        self.current = value

#Main application
class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.sm = MyScreenManager()
        return self.sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**kv**

```
<MyScreenManager>:

    Screen1:
        name: 'screen1'
    Screen2:
        name: 'screen2'
    Screen3:
        name: 'screen3'

<Screen1>:

    GridLayout:

        rows: 2
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 2'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen2'

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 3'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen3'

        Label:
            text: 'You are on ' + root.name

<Screen2>:

    GridLayout:

        rows: 2
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 1'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 3'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen3'

        Label:
            text: 'You are on ' + root.name

<Screen3>:

    GridLayout:

        rows: 2
        padding: 20
        spacing: 20

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 1'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen1'

        Button:
            text: 'Go to Screen 2'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'screen2'

        Label:
            text: 'You are on ' + root.name
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I personally like the slimmer, code less version from eyllanesc though